# How to combine only the value of checked checkbox and its value into one array and post into database without session

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to post data into the database but could only find an array method after looking up for so long.
With my codes, I used checkbox for productName and text input for quantity and I posted the values in arrays while merging them to make into a string but the output is not what I wanted.

The way I want the output is: "Item, Quantity, Item, Quantity" and only the quantity of the checked checkbox.

This is my code for getting data of the checkbox and value

```
<div class="container blog-holder">
        <form action="pre-order.php" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <section id="wrap-content" class="blog-3col-grid">
                    <div class="row">
                    <?php        
                        $checked_arr = array();
                        $getMenu = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE  status != 0");
                        if(!empty($getMenu)) {
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getMenu)) {
                                $productID = $row['menu_id'];
                                $productName = $row['name'];
                                $image = $row['image'];
                                $image_src = "process/menuPhoto/".$image;
                                $checked = "";
                    ?>    
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <article class="blog-item blog-item-3col-grid">
                        <a href="blog-single-post.html">
                              <div class="post-image"> <img src="<?php echo $image_src ?>" /> </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="post-holder post-content content-grid">
                            <ul class="post-meta">
                                <li class="meta-date"><?php echo $row['category']; ?></li>
                                <li class="meta-categ">RM <?php echo $row['price']; ?></li>
                            </ul>
                            <h2 class="article-title"><a href="blog-single-post.html"><?php ?></a></h2>
                            <div class="article-excerpt">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="productName[id_<?=$productID?>]" class="orderedItems" value="<?php echo $productName; ?>" $checked /><tag style="align: right">  <?php echo $productName; ?></tag>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                            <select class="form-control" name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" style="width: 12em;">
                                <option name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" value= "1">1</option>
                                <option name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" value= "2">2</option>
                                <option name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" value= "3">3</option>
                                <option name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" value= "4">4</option>
                                <option name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" value= "5">5</option>
                                <option name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" value= "6">6</option>
                                <option name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" value= "7">7</option>
                                <option name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" value= "8">8</option>
                                <option name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" value= "9">9</option>
                                <option name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]" value= "10">10</option>
                        </select>
                           </div>
                        </article>
                     </div>
                     <?php } } ?>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the process to POST data into the database

```
<?php   

    include 'process/db_connect.php';  
    
    $values = array();
    $quantity = array();
    
    //Add Pre-order
    if(isset($_POST['makePreOrder'])) {
        
        $product = $_POST['name'] ?? [];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'] ?? [];
        $merged = array_merge_recursive((array)$product, (array)$quantity);
        
        $squashed = array_map(function($v){
            return is_array($v)
                ? implode(' ', $v)
                : $v;
        }, $merged);
        
        $string = var_export($squashed, TRUE);
        
        $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $string);
        
        echo $takePreOrder = "INSERT INTO reservation (name, contact, date, time, seats, message, orders, status, createdTime) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[contact]', '$_POST[date]', '$_POST[time]', '$_POST[seats]', '$_POST[message]', '$string', 0, now())";
        mysqli_query($con, $takePreOrder);
        exit();

        if(!$takePreOrder) {
            printf("%s\n", $con->error);
            exit();
        }

        if($takePreOrder === TRUE) {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../pre-order.php?Reservation=success'>";
        } else {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../pre-order.php?Reservation=fail'>";
        }
    }
```

The result is

```
INSERT INTO reservation (name, contact, date, time, seats, message, orders, status, createdTime) VALUES ('Test n', '0123456789', '2020-11-26', '15:00', '8', 'Test Message', 'array (\n 0 => \'Test n\',\n \'id_1\' => \'9\',\n \'id_2\' => \'8\',\n \'id_3\' => \'1\',\n \'id_4\' => \'1\',\n)', 0, now())
```

But the product name wouldnt show and the array(), \n and => appears.
Is there a way to make the string like "Item 1, 10, Item 2, 5"? (Item, Quantity, Item, Quantity)

Comment: Reading this on my phone, so hard to dig into the code much. But I’m seeing some red flags:  1) You’re open to SQL injection (use prepared statements instead of real escape string), 2) You’re trying to store array data into a single field? need to redesign db table? 3) The purpose of the checkbox is not immediately clear to me, and it doesn’t seem to have anything to do with the query anyway

Comment: Hi @Tim Morton, yes I'm still new to the field. Would you advice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using `array_merge_recursive` which will merge both the array by appending the second array to the first one. Since you want the items in specific comma seperated order it is better to use a loop to arrange it the way you want. The code below should work as you want it.

From [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

> If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

```
$productID = $_POST['productID'] ?? [];
$mergedStr = "";

for($i=0; $i<count($productID); $i++) {
    if(isset($_POST['productName-' . $productID[i]]))
     $mergedStr .= ', ' . $_POST['productName-' . $productID[i]] . ' , ' . $_POST['quantity-' . $productID[i]];
}

$mergedStr = preg_replace('/, /i', '', $mergedStr, 1); //remove leading comma
$mergedStr =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $mergedStr);

// Make sure to escape all of the values, especially user inputs before inserting into MySQL.
// Use PDO Prepared statements: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
// echo $takePreOrder = "INSERT INTO reservation (name, contact, date, time, seats, message, orders, status, createdTime) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[contact]', '$_POST[date]', '$_POST[time]', '$_POST[seats]', '$_POST[message]', '$mergedStr', 0, now())";
```

The HTML part:

You were setting the name of the input fields as `name="quantity[id_<?=$productID?>]"` but you can't access them in php as an array.

Since `productName` is a checkbox and it won't show up in the `$_POST` array unless it's checked we make a new hidden field with the product IDs. This field won't show in the frontend to the user but it will have the value of the product id which can then be used to access the productName and the quantity.

```
            <input type="hidden" name="productID[]" value="<?php echo $productID; ?>"/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="productName-<?=$productID?>" class="orderedItems" value="<?php echo $productName; ?>" $checked />
            <tag style="align: right">  <?php echo $productName; ?></tag>
            <br>
         </div>
         <select class="form-control" name="quantity-<?=$productID?>" style="width: 12em;">
            <option value= "1">1</option>
            <option value= "2">2</option>
            <option value= "3">3</option>
            <option value= "4">4</option>
            <option value= "5">5</option>
            <option value= "6">6</option>
            <option value= "7">7</option>
            <option value= "8">8</option>
            <option value= "9">9</option>
            <option value= "10">10</option>
         </select>
```

This script relies on the quantity array having at least as many values as the product array.

The output I got using a modified version of the script above,

`Item 1, 10, Item 2, 2`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @kks21199!  
I've tried implementing the snippet above. However I got an error returned that states  
`PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /public_html/pre-order.php on line 26` <br/>
while the output shows 
`INSERT INTO reservation (name, contact, date, time, seats, message, orders, status, createdTime) VALUES ('Test', '0123456789', '2020-11-18', '17:00', '8', 'Message Test', '', 0, now())`

Comment: @Art can you share the code of your HTML form with me? You also specify you need checked checkbox fields only but your PHP code doesn't show anything related to checkboxes?

Comment: How can I share it to you @kks21199? Sorry I'm new to using stack. It's actually up there, just in red I have no idea why.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check and let me know if this works. The function also checks whether the checkbox is checked before printing the quantity.

Comment: Thank you very much @kks21199! It's working already.

Comment: @Art while reading my answer I found a logic flaw. I have updated it again and added explanation as well. Please check if it works for you now.

Comment: Thanks again @kks21199 for the advice. I've amended my codes, and it's working well!